# poly2tri - triangle's IsInterior property - properly configuration

Tags: c#, triangulation

I want to draw figure with hole.

[image: result I wanna]

To do this, I have to cut figure to triangles and draw them one by one.

[image: triangulated picture]

Here I have eight exterior triangles and two interior. I thought, that I'll take only exteriors and draw them like

```
const int y = 100;
const int x = 100;
const int offset = 20;

IList<PolygonPoint> bounds = new List<PolygonPoint>
{
    new PolygonPoint(0,0),
    new PolygonPoint(0, y),
    new PolygonPoint(x, y),
    new PolygonPoint(x, 0),
};

IList<PolygonPoint> hole = new List<PolygonPoint>
{
    new PolygonPoint(offset, offset),
    new PolygonPoint(x - offset, offset),
    new PolygonPoint(offset, y - offset),
    new PolygonPoint(x - offset, y - offset),
};

Polygon polygon = new Polygon(bounds); // here polygon contains four dots
polygon.AddHole(new Polygon(hole)); // and here - eight

P2T.Triangulate(polygon); // here I get ten triangles

foreach (var triangle in polygon.Triangles.Where(tr => tr.IsInterior)) // <-- problem
{
    // draw
}
```

But every triangle in the polygon has IsInterior == true. What I'm doing wrong?

P.S. And for PointSet this property is always false in the same case.

Comment: Every triangle is inside the rectangle ABCD so they are all interior.   You only want triangles inside/outside hole.

Comment: @jdweng , it's a problem if so. I have no access to holes: they are private.

Comment: Make following change from : polygon.AddHole(new Polygon(hole));   To : Polygon hole = new Polygon(hole); polygon.AddHole(hole);

Comment: @jdweng , this is not a solution due to two things: first of all, holes are private not by random: there's a reason to encapsulate them, and I don't like break this stuff. And second: I don't know how to take diff between two polygons anyway; and I suppose, that poly2tri can't do this. Clip2tri can, i think, but there's no nuget package for .NET. I'm afraid, that I must make it, but... Oh, so many things for making simple property working... Poly2tri's authors will not add holes functionality without working holes' api, I just need to find it.

Comment: What I did is no different then current code.  I just broke one instruction into two so you can get the interior triangles of the hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn, it was easier, that I thought.

I had wrong point order.

It have to be

```
IList<PolygonPoint> hole = new List<PolygonPoint>
{
    new PolygonPoint(offset, offset),
    new PolygonPoint(offset, y - offset),
    new PolygonPoint(x - offset, y - offset),
    new PolygonPoint(x - offset, offset),
};
```

All except this part works pretty fine, and the result looks like this:

[image: correct triangles]

Thank for all been here!